# SpringBoot2 - jpa entity is not a managed type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a class marked with `javax.persistence.Entity` which `SpringBoot` says is not a managed type.

The class is as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String name;

@Column(unique = true)
private String username;

...
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUsername(String username);

    List<User> findByName(String name);

    @Query("UPDATE AppUser u SET u.lastLogin=:lastLogin WHERE u.username = ?#{ principal?.username }")
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    public void updateLastLogin(@Param("lastLogin") Date lastLogin);

}
```

AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        userRepository.updateLastLogin(new Date());
    }

}
```

and SpringSecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.bae.dbauth.security")
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl successHandler;
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void completeSetup() {
        userDetailsService = applicationContext.getBean(CustomUserDetailsService.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(encoder())
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll()
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    }

    ....

}
```

And the application class...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence-h2.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.bae.dbauth.repositories" })
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(SpringSecurityConfig.class)
public class BaeDbauthApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.bae.dbauth.models" });
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BaeDbauthApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I run the application I get quite long an error message which includes `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.bae.dbauth.model.User`

The whole stack trace is quite extensive, it starts with:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'successHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationSuccessHandlerImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.bae.dbauth.model.User
```

And I don't understand what is the problem with the User class.

**UPDATE:**
I added/modified annotations in `SpringSecurityCongig.java` and tried

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan({"com.bae.dbauth.security", "com.bae.dbauth.model"})
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.bae.dbauth.security")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.bae.dbauth.model"})
```

where `com.bae.dbauth.model` is package where the `User` entity is while `com.bae.dbauth` is the package where `SpringSecurityConfig.java` and the main `application` class are.

The result is the same in each case - the same error message.

Comment: What is the package name of your `User` class and `Application` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entity is not discovered. If you have your entity manager factoryauto-configured, you have 2 options:

- add @EntityScan
- place your entities in a package that is under your application (these packages are scanned by convention)

I can see that you configure your entity manager factory yourself.

```
em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.bae.dbauth.models" });
```

While your user entity is in: `com.bae.dbauth.model`

This makes me think this is simply a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from annotations on application class, in case you've multiple DB's configured (or DB configuration defined separately; @Bean of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean), then ensure that you've defined correct packages with the builder (EntityManagerFactoryBuilder).

e.g

```java
           builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.xyz.abc.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("application-db")
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first to change in `User`the type of `id` to `Long` instead of `long`.

Then make sure the `@ComponentScan` includes also the java package containing the entities. You can specify more than one package to scan, see [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html#basePackages--). E ample:

```
@ComponentScan({"pkg1","pkg2"})
```

Comment: Done, but still the same error message is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Add annotation `@Repository` in UserRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

     User findByUsername(String username);
     List<User> findByName(String name);
     @Query("UPDATE AppUser u SET u.lastLogin=:lastLogin WHERE u.username = ?#{ principal?.username }")

     @Modifying
     @Transactional
     public void updateLastLogin(@Param("lastLogin") Date lastLogin);
}
```